# PHP CLI doesn't use stderr to output errors

Tags: stdout, stderr, php, nstask

I'm running the PHP CLI through a NSTask in MacOS, but this question is more about the CLI itself.

I'm listening to the `stderr` pipe, but nothing is output there no matter what file I try to run:

- If the file type is not a plain text, `stdout` sets to `?`.
- If the file is a php script with errors, the error messages are still printed to `stdout`.

Is there a switch to the interpreter to handle errors through `stderr`? Do I have an option to detect errors other than parsing `stdout`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The [`display_errors` directive](http://php.net/errorfunc.configuration#ini.display-errors) (can be set everywhere) takes optionally the parameter "`stderr`" for it to report errors to *stderr* instead of *stdout* or completely disabled error output. Quoting from the PHP manual entry:

> Value *"stderr"* sends the errors to *stderr* instead of *stdout*. The value is available as of PHP 5.2.4.

Alternatively if you're using the commandline interface and you want to output the errors your own you can re-use the [command-line nput/output streams](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.io-streams.php):

```
fwrite(STDERR, 'error message');
```

Here `STDERR` is an already opened stream to *stderr*.

Alternatively if you want to do it just for this script and not in CLI you can open a filed handler to `php://stderr` and write the error messages there.

```
$fe = fopen('php://stderr', 'w');
fwrite($fe, 'error message');
```

Answer (score 9):

If you want the error messages sent by the php interpreter should go to the `stderr`-pipe, you must set [`display_errors`](http://php.net/errorfunc.configuration#ini.display-errors) to `stderr`

Answer (score 2):

This is required to return from PHP realm into shell environment in order to parse properly error message. You still need to exit(1) or whatever integer in order to return exit status code from PHP to shell.

```
fwrite(STDERR, 'error message'); //output message into 2> buffer
exit(0x0a); //return error status code to shell
```

Then, your crontab entry will look like:

```
30 3 * * * /usr/bin/php /full/path/to/phpFile.php >> /logdir/fullpath/journal.log 2>> /logdir/fullpath/error_journal.log
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use **file_put_contents()** with *"php://stderr"* to output to standard error, like:

```
php -r 'file_put_contents("php://stderr", "Hiya, PHP!\n"); echo "Bye!\n";' 1>/dev/null
```

which outputs "Hiya, PHP!\n" to standard error and nothing to standard output when executed in a Bash shell.