# using php from command line: how to redirect output?

Tags: php, bash, shell

I'm a PHP newbie... I usually script with bash, where I can easily do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# myscript.sh

function testFunction() {
 echo "bubu" > /dev/tty
 echo "gaga"
}
a=$(testFunction)
echo $a > t
```

If I run it in a shell I get this:

```
$ ./myscript.sh
bubu
$ cat t
gaga
```

Now, how can I get the same output if I have a PHP file instead of the function?

```
// my script.php
echo "bubu";
echo "gaga";
```

Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# myscript.sh

a=$(php myscript.php)
echo $a > t
```

If I run it in a shell I get this:

```
$ ./myscript.sh
$ cat t
bubu
gaga
```

How can I tell the php script to send `"bubu"` to `/dev/tty`?

I tried and play around with `ob_start` and his friends, but didn't get any result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use stdout/stderr in PHP to split the output, see stackoverflow question [PHP CLI doesn't use stderr to output errors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6447567/367456). This would however require to adapt all "bubu" `echo` statements in `myscript.php` to something like:

```
fwrite(STDERR, "bubu");
```

You would then redirect *stderr* to file `bubu` in the Bash wrapper to get all the "bubu" lines, while all the "gaga" lines would appear on your terminal:

```
php myscript.php 2> bubu
```

Comment: thanks michael... but: is there a way in php to send something to stderr without writing to a file? it sounds pretty much expensive if running within a cicle, isn't it?

Comment: `fwrite` does not write to an actual file in this case, so there is no disk I/O in the PHP part. You should not call `fopen` for each write however, just do that once at program start. There is another way using [error_log()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php), unless `error_log` is set to a specific file, but that further decreases performance compared to `fwrite`. My test setup (a simple loop) completed 10000 iterations with `echo` in 35 ms, with `fwrite` in 41 ms, and with `error_log` in 45 ms.

Comment: great, that's definitely sounds as a good solution... many thanks!

Comment: You don't even need to open that stream handle in command-line. I've edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score -2):

```
$ php script.php > /dev/tty
```

That does the trick :)

edit/

I see, you want just the "bubu"

so, you should do the following:

```
file_put_contents('/dev/tty', 'bubu');
```

Comment: This will send everything there (which is already the default anyway in a way) and does not split the output the way the OP wants).