# Output a STDERR for PHP errors without changing php.ini

Tags: php, .htaccess, error-handling, cron, stderr

I have some PHP scripts that run every minute via CRON. I don't want to receive emails every time they run correctly but I do want to receive an email if they throw an error (e.g. if they use too much memory).

To run the CRON:

- - - - - php myscript.php >/dev/null

This should send an email only when the result of `stderr` is not null, i.e. when there is a standard error.

However, PHP errors don't create a `stderr`, instead they are included in the `stdout` so no email is sent.

I have tried setting `display_errors` to `stderr` as shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447567/php-cli-doesnt-use-stderr-to-output-errors) but it's a different use case as the scripts are not run by CRON. I have tried the following which have not worked:

including this in the script itself doesn't work because a fatal errors mean the script doesn't run:

```
ini_set ('display_errors', 'stderr');
```

including this in an .htaccess file (note PHP FPM is used) didn't work - I'm not sure why:

```
php_flag display_errors stderr
```

Changing the php.ini file is not an option because I don't want the change to affect the whole site, just a few files.

So my question is - how can the PHP errors be sent to `stderr` so that I can receive them via email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `php` executable takes command line options - you can either specify *which* php.ini it should use, or set specific config options via the `-d` parameter.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php

Comment: Thanks for answering - does this mean I can add a php.ini file specifically for the scripts that I want it to affect?

Comment: Yes, with `php -c /path/to.php.ini` you can specify, which php.ini it should use, to execute the specified script file. If you don’t need to change anything but where the error output is send, then `php -d display_errors=stderr` sould also do the trick here.

Comment: I tried running `php -d display_errors=stderr my_script.php >/dev/null` and it still didn't work.